# HTML - apply stlysheet to specific div

Tags: html, css

How to apply a stylesheet to a specific nav or div? for instance:

```
<head>
    <meta CharacterSet='UTF-8'>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.staticfile.org/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.staticfile.org/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.staticfile.org/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/main.js' %}"></script>
    {% block script %}{% endblock %}
</head>


    <nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand mb-0" href="#">Pizza</a>
            </div>
            {% if user is not none %}
            <div id="navbar-collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    {% block nav_list %}{% endblock %}
                </ul>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="{% url 'logout' %}" method="get">
                    <span>Welcome, {{ user }}.&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                    <button id="logout" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Log out</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </nav>
```

in above code, how to apply "`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.staticfile.org/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">`" only to the part of `<nav>...</nav>`, without affecting the rest of the document.

Comment: You can't. Loading external css affecting to all of html.

Comment: You could use a [ShadowRoot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot) feature which allows you create a somewhat isolated DOM subtree, but i'm not sure if it actually worth in your case.

Comment: Why not just take from that stylesheet the styles you need. copy paste them into your CSS and....thats it. Because you just need the styles for nav.

Comment: How to identify all of the styles for nav

Comment: aaa... the ones that have ` nav `  related selectors ? :)

Comment: @Mihai T this is really difficault since there are too many of them...

Comment: well choose the ones you need :)

Comment: the problem is I dont know which one is the one I need (I need some of styles while others are making my page very ugly). I have filtered all 'nav' selectors. How to I limit the scope to only the nav bar related styles at the page top, cause other things are affecting the entire page.